handlebars arithmetic opperations
i am using handlebars to make a template to hold the chords of a song in a table. I have it working so that the chords are all in their own cells and 1 cell per row. However, I cant find a way to change the dimensions of the table. like make it have 4 cells per row for example
here is the functional version of the code that has 1 cell per row
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title> {{title}} </title>
<style type="text/css">
table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
   font-size: 20px;
}
td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <div> 
      <h1>{{song.id}}  title: {{song.title}}</h1> 
      <p>composer: {{song.composer}}</p> 
      <p>key: {{song.key}}</p> 
      <p>bars: {{song.bars}}</p> 
      <table>
      {{#each song.individualBars}} 
         <tr>
         <td>{{this}}</td> 
         </tr>
      {{/each}} 
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

and here is what I came up with for a 4 wide table
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title> {{title}} </title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
   font-size: 20px;
}
td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <div> 
      <h1>{{song.id}}  title: {{song.title}}</h1> 
      <p>composer: {{song.composer}}</p> 
      <p>key: {{song.key}}</p> 
      <p>bars: {{song.bars}}</p> 
      <table>
      {{#each song.individualBars}}
         {{#if @index % 4 == 0}}
            <tr>
         {{/if}}
         <td>{{this}}</td> 
         {{#if @index % 4 == 3}}
            </tr>
         {{/if}}
      {{/each}} 
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>


however, this gave me the following error upon testing
Parse error on line 28:
...       {{#if @index % 4 == 0}}
        
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

Not sure if this is of any use but here is the javascript function i use to split the individual chords
exports.songDetails = function(request, response){
    
var urlObj = parseURL(request, response);
var songID = urlObj.path; //expected form: /song/235
songID = songID.substring(songID.lastIndexOf("/")+1, songID.length);
    
var sql = "SELECT id, title, composer, key, bars FROM songs WHERE id=" + songID;
console.log("GET SONG DETAILS: " + songID );
    
   db.all(sql, function(err, rows){
    let song = rows[0];
    song.individualBars = [];

    // Split bars string into individual bars using '|]', '||', or '|'
    let bars = song.bars.split(/\|\||\|\]|\|/);

    // Iterate through each bar and extract chord information
    bars.forEach(bar => {
        let chords = bar.split('|').filter(Boolean); // Remove empty strings
        song.individualBars.push(chords);
    });

    console.log('Song Details');
    console.log(song);
    response.render('songDetails', {title: 'Songs Details:', song:  song});
});

}

yeah thats really usefull thanks. Sorry i couldnt find that post or i would have used that instead
